# HttpContextBase dependency on IPrincipal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have the following windsor setup:

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<HttpContextBase>().
                UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IPrincipal>().
                UsingFactoryMethod(() => HttpContext.Current.User).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

I am then trying to resolve HttpContextBase before the HttpContext.Current.User property has been set.  During the resolve of HttpContextBase, windsor tries to resolve IPrincipal which is null, and an exception is thrown.

If I replace the resolve with what I thought it should be doing i.e.

```
new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)
```

then my code works.

Can someone explain why Windsor tries to resolve IPrincipal for HttpContextBase?  Can I stop it doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor tries to inject property dependencies as-well. You have to say explicitly, you don't want to.

```
Component.For<HttpContextBase>().Properties(PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll))...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Windsor did that!

Comment: You welcome and go read some cool stuff about your container. It is really powerful think. http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx It is worth it.